# Including the Geos library into a new Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, geos

It's been years since I used C++ and so I'm very rusty. I'm trying to test out the Geos library, but I'm unable to get a simple Hello World example to compile

https://libgeos.org/usage/download/

This is what I tried:

1. I downloaded and extracted the files
2. Created a new C++ project in Visual Studio
3. Added the headers folder into the Visual Studio Include Directories for the project.

Then I tried to use the library in my main.cpp:

```
#include <geos/geom/PrecisionModel.h>
#include <geos/geom/Polygon.h>
#include <geos/geom/LinearRing.h>
#include <geos/geom/CoordinateSequenceFactory.h>
#include <geos/geom/Geometry.h>
#include <geos/geom/GeometryFactory.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

geos::geom::Polygon * MakeBox(double xmin, double ymin, double xmax, double ymax) {
    std::unique_ptr<geos::geom::PrecisionModel> pm(new geos::geom::PrecisionModel());

    geos::geom::GeometryFactory::unique_ptr factory = geos::geom::GeometryFactory::create(pm.get(), -1);
    geos::geom::CoordinateSequence* temp = factory->getCoordinateSequenceFactory()->create((std::size_t)0, 0);

    temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(xmin, ymin));
    temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(xmin, ymax));
    temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(xmax, ymax));
    temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(xmax, ymin));
    //Must close the linear ring or we will get an error:
    //"Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring"
    temp->add(geos::geom::Coordinate(xmin, ymin));

    geos::geom::LinearRing* shell = factory->createLinearRing(temp);

    //NULL in this case could instead be a collection of one or more holes
    //in the interior of the polygon
    return factory->createPolygon(shell, NULL);
}

int main() {
    geos::geom::Polygon* box = MakeBox(0, 0, 10, 10);
    std::cout << box->getArea() << std::endl;
    delete box; //Important to avoid memory leaks
}
```

I'm getting multiple errors, but they all seem to indicate that the library is not loaded correctly

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
> (active)  E0135   class "geos::geom::GeometryFactory" has no member
> "unique_ptr"  TestGeos    C:\TestGeos\TestGeos.cpp    15

What am I missing in order to use the library?

Comment: Not to point out the obvious, but unique_ptr is part of the STL, not Geos

Comment: `geos::geom::GeometryFactory::unique_ptr` looks unusual. You may be able to use `auto` instead of that.

Comment: The example [code](https://libgeos.org/usage/cpp_api/) shows `GeometryFactory::Ptr factory = GeometryFactory::create();` instead of what you are trying. `geos::geom::GeometryFactory::unique_ptr factory = geos::geom::GeometryFactory::create(pm.get(), -1);`

Comment: It looks like you wanted to write `GeometryFactory::Ptr factory =geos::geom::GeometryFactory::create(pm.get(), -1);` using this create() method: [https://libgeos.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1geom_1_1GeometryFactory.html#ae9099381789bdf714157906fdf1001a2](https://libgeos.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1geom_1_1GeometryFactory.html#ae9099381789bdf714157906fdf1001a2)

Comment: What language standard are you using? unique_ptr requires c++17 and needs to be prefixed with std::.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks! Using the example code got rid of the compile errors, but now I'm getting a Link error Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\...\geos-3.11.1\out\build\x64-Debug\bin.obj'

Comment: Looks like an improper setting in your linker settings. Some how you have a `bin` in the list of object and library dependencies.